# Pairwise Non Isomorphic 3-regular Graphs of certain orders

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am currently reviewing some graph theory before an exam and ran into the following problem which has me fairly stumped.

The number of pairwise non-isomorphic 3-regular graphs of order 8 is 6, the number of pairwise non-isomorphic 3-regular graphs of order 10 is 21, and the number of pairwise non-isomorphic 3-regular graphs of order 14 is 540.  Using this information, determine the number of pairwise non-isomorphic connected 3-regular graphs of order 14.

I know that pairwise non-isomorphic graphs means that no two graphs in the set of graphs for a said order should be the same, i.e. it should have a bijection in each pair of graph's vertex sets.

However, I'm unsure how to utilise the previous orders to determine the number when the order is 14.

Any hints and help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what information can be used and what needs to be determined.

Comment: Using this information, determine the number of pairwise non-isomorphic connected 3-regular graphs of order 14.

Comment: Any information regarding graph theory and the number of graphs in each of the provided orders can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use cubic instead of $3$-regular.

We are tasked with finding the number of isomorphism types for cubic graphs of degree $3$ that are connected.

We are told there is $540$ isomorphism types for cubic graphs on $14$ vertices total, so we must only count the disconnected isomorphism types and substract it from this number, fortunately these ones are easy to do.

The connected components of such a graph can have sizes $4,6,8$ or $10$ ($12$ isn't possible because $2$ is not possible).

Hence we just have to iterate over the partitions of $14$ into sizes from this list and see how many possibilities each allows. There can be at most $3$ summands and the only one with $3$ summands is $(4,4,6)$, the other options have two summands and it is easy to see they are $(4,10)$ and $(6,8)$

Option $1$ is $(4,4,6)$. Note there is only one cubic connected graph with $4$ vertices so those components must be $K_4$, there are two isomorphism types with $6$ vertices though. Hence there is $2$ isomorphism types with components of sizes $(4,4,6)$.

Option $2$ is $(4,10)$, there are $1 \cdot 1 \cdot 21$. One component must be $K_4$ and the other has $21$ options, so there are $21$ isomorphism types with sizes $(4,10)$.

Option $3$ is $(6,8)$, there are $2$ options for the component of size $6$ and $6$ for the component of size $8$.

Hence there are $2+21+12 = 35$ isomorphism types for cubic disconnected graphs of order $14$.

Comment: In your option 3 you mention that we have 2 options for component size 6 and 6 for component size 8. This results in a total of 8 which is not in the final calculation. Have you mistakenly put 12 instead of 8 in the final sum for the cubic disconnected graphs of order 14 or am I misinterpreting something here?

Comment: I believe I misinterpreted the multiplication of 2 and 6 as the addition of 2 and 6. I see how we arrive at 12.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just to clarify one point in @Yorch's answer.

If a cubic graph of order $14$ is not connected, then it has one of the following three sets of components: $4$, $4$, $6$; $6$, $8$; $4$, $10$.

For $4$, $4$, $6$ there are $2$ cubic graphs;

for $6$, $8$ there are $12$ cubic graphs;

for $4$, $10$ there are $21$ cubic graphs.

But two graphs for $4$, $4$, $6$ are counted three times. Therefore we get $21+12+2-4=31$ and there are $509$ connected cubic graphs of order $14$.

Comment: I see. I was concerned regarding a counting error but didn't consider it to intersect over the options. As commented on @Yorch's answer can you clarify how there are 12 3-regular graphs for the partition (6,8) when it has been described as there being 6 of order 8 and 2 of order 6?

Comment: I misinterpreted the multiplication of 2 and 6 as the addition of 2 and 6. I see how we arrive at 12.

Could you further clarify how the two graphs are counted three times for the (4,4,6) partition?

Comment: @Goblin_27 For example, the number of non-isomorphic cubic graphs of order $10$ is $21$. But this number also includes those graphs that have connected components of size $4$ and $6$.

Comment: Ah I see. So we must subtract those that are counted numerous times as they reappear in the other partitions. Thanks for the clarification!